# xmlhttprequest on google chrome, sometimes return net::connection_reset error

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

i've been tasked create a xhr post request to websocket server,

however whenever chrome is used, it returns net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 50% of the time.

this does not occurs on other browser as tested on safari, firefox, and microsoft edge.

```
function doPost(url, data) {
    promisePost(url, data)
    .then(
        function (val) {
            console.log("returns: " + val);

        }, function (error) {
            console.log("error: " + error);
        })
};

var promisePost = function (url, data) {
     return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        try {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.upload.onabort = function () {
                reject("aborted by user");
            };

            xhr.timeout = 5000;

            xhr.ontimeout = function () {
                reject("error@timeout");
            };

            var handleStateChange = function () {

                switch (xhr.readyState) {

                    case 4:
                        //responses
                        if (xhr.status == 0) {
                            //undefined error it return xhrstatus 0
                            reject("error@xhrcode:" + xhr.status);
                        } else {
                            if (xhr.responseText == "") {
                                reject("error@response is empty");
                            } else
                                resolve("done@xhrcode:" + xhr.status + "@responses:" + xhr.responseText);
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        //error with statuscode
                        reject("error@xhrcode:" + xhr.status + "@responses:" + xhr.responseText);
                };
            };

            xhr.onerror = function (e) {
                reject("status code: " + xhr.status + " " + e);
            };
            xhr.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange;
            xhr.open("POST", url, true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
            xhr.send(data);

        } catch (e) {
            //error in script
            reject("scerror " + e.message);
        }})
};
```

i'm 100% certain that the server already have cors support since i've been testing it via other browser.

anyone got any idea how to solve this? been stuck on this for past 3 weeks

Comment: problem is not in your code, something is wrong with server side. check http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-1982982/err-connection-reset-error-chrome.html . If your request is too "havy", check your server properties, maybe it just drops connetions on timeout

Comment: the thing is the same code works fine in other browser with the same amount of data being transmitted, net::connection_reset error only seems to exist on google chrome. if the server are getting to heavy and just dropped the connection, im pretty sure that error or similar will be shown on other browser.

Comment: are you testing from local browsers, or from remote PCs, or throughVPN?

Comment: maybe it is software bug?